# Test if a pressed button performs a redirect to a correct page?

Tags: javascript, typescript, redirect, automated-tests, playwright

I'm writing a test with playwright, and I'd like to know the most correct way to check if - after a press of a button - it emitted a redirect to the expected URL, in order to pass the test.

I've found this snippet but it gets stuck:

```
const [request] = await Promise.all([
    // Waits for the next request with the specified url
    page.waitForRequest('*URL*'),
    // Triggers the request
    page.click('button'),
  ]);
```

It first clicks on the button, the redirect happens, but then it keeps waiting for the request anyway.

Answer (score 4):

Will `waitForNavigation()` work for you?

```js
const [response] = await Promise.all([
    // Waits for the main frame navigation and returns the main resource response 
    page.waitForNavigation({url: '*URL*'}),
    // Triggers the request
    page.click('button'),
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As `waitForNavigation` is deprecated, I recommend to use `page.waitForURL(url)`.

More: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-url